# Parameterize tests to user with different setting each time

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, playwright

I'm trying to run the same tests for different user settings I have,
My implementation is to loop through the user setting array and update the user setting before the tests run...
the issue I face is due to the asynchronous nature of the playwright tests and the way JavaScript handles loops, all my tests always  run with the last 'tier2' user settings.
any suggestion on how to approach that test case? (I want to be able to run the tests in parallel)

here is a code example:

```
import {test} from '@playwright/test'
import updateUserSettings from '../utils/updateUserSettings'
import checkApiPermissions from '../helpers/checkApiPermissions'


const userSettingArray = ['admin', 'tier1', 'tier2'];
const endpointArray = ['users', 'settings', 'message', 'image', 'video', 'search', 'about']

async function testHelper() {
    for( const settings of userSettingArray) {
        await updateUserSettings(settings);

        for(const endpoint of endpointArray){
            test(`test ${settings} settings`, ()=> {
                await checkApiPermissions(settings, endpoint);
            });
        }
    }
}

testHelper().catch(console.error)
```

I tried to run the tests in parallel for each user settings

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I recommend using fixtures. By that you have full control of your test case. You can pass your predefined configuration to your test case where needed. [create fixtures](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures#creating-a-fixture), [usage of fixures](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures#using-a-fixture). For instance, your TC1 needs setting 'tier1' -> apply fixture 'fixture-user'-setting-1', your TC2 needs setting 'admin' -> apply fixture 'fixture-admin-setting'. Advantage is , when you configured your fixture once you only need to apply where needed.